# Compare each key in dict with explicit differentiation for 1 key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python code that compares dict values for all the keys in the 1st dict variable

```
any(spec_copy[k] != actual_specs_copy[k] for k in spec_copy.keys())
```

What I want is to have all keys except for one key. For that particular key I want to have my own way of comparison.

Comment: `any(some if cond else other for ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your conditional check into a ternary operator and then do your special check in a separate function (or in a lamda) - you can even pass some arguments to your check function if you wish. Here's a simplified version:

```
d1 = d2 = {
    'some_key': 1,
    'special_key': 2,
}
def my_check():
    return False

print( any(d1[k] != d2[k] if (k != 'special_key') else my_check() for k in d1.keys() ) )
```